# Crear una app con menús y submenus en Python Tkinter con radio Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radiobutton

Me podrían ayudar a crear una app que contenga menús y submenús con radio Button en Python Tkinter y que tenga funcionalidad de las opciones que se le agreguen. Gracias

```
from Tkinter import *
Root = Tk()

menubar = Menu (root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
```

Comment: Por favor, añade lo que hayas intentado, aquí no hacemos deberes y tienes que añadir tu esfuerzo por solucionar el problema, sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Disculpa, es que soy nueva y no sabía mucho sobre las políticas del sitio web

Comment: Como resumen breve para próximas preguntas: Queremos ver que estas atascada y que lo has intentado todo. Necesitamos el código que te falla y el mensaje explicito de error en texto, no imágenes o capturas de pantalla. Tampoco resolvemos dudas del estilo: "¿Cuál es mejor...?", o en general preguntas que se basen en opiniones ni tampoco te "hacemos los deberes". Esto último en general suele saltar mucho a la vista porque los usuarios suelen copiar y pegar el texto de la pregunta de la asignatura así sin más. Vuelve cuando tengas algo más elaborado y lo vemos. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si aún estás muy nueva en Python te recomiendo no entrar directamente en el mundo de Tkinter, practica un poco mas, pero si aún así requieres realizar este programa te recomiendo usar [Pygubu](https://pypi.org/project/pygubu/) y [Pygubu designer](https://pypi.org/project/pygubu-designer/) para realizar una interfaz con **Tkinter**, es un programa de "arrastrar y soltar". También tiene la ventaja de que te genera el código fuente de la aplicación, no solo el código de la interfaz, por ejemplo, si colocas un botón, te crea la función que se va a ejecutar al presionar dicho botón, sin embargo tampoco es milagrosa la librería, la mayor parte de la lógica la debes poner tú. Pásate por el [repositorio](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu-designer) de **Pygubu Designer** para aprender sobre su uso.